# shell sort with very strange order output

Tags: shell, sorting, sh

I'm sorting (and removing dups) with a text file using.  It's removing the dups just fine.

The original file is fairly randomized in the format - here's a small test case:

```
(q0 (q1 a))
(q1p (q1c c))
(q1q (q1 e))
(q1 (q2 s))
```

Once sorted I get silliness:

```
sort -u text > outfile

(q0 (q1 a))
(q1p (q1c c))
(q1 (q2 s))
(q1q (q1 e))
```

By a bit of testing apparently the q1 (or q2 or whatever) will fall between q1p and q1q. Why on earth would a blank fall between these two chars?  I'd prefer the "q1 " to go ahead of the "q1".  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Is `LANG` set in your environment, or any variable starting with `LC_`? What are they set to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my default locale, I get the same result that you do:

```
$ sort -u text
(q0 (q1 a))
(q1p (q1c c))
(q1 (q2 s))
(q1q (q1 e))
```

To get the results that you want, use the C locale:

```
$ LC_ALL=C sort -u text
(q0 (q1 a))
(q1 (q2 s))
(q1p (q1c c))
(q1q (q1 e))
```

Comment: Fabulous!  I could NOT find this.  Thanks so much!